# Merging two json files into one?

Tags: json, powershell

I have two `.Json` files I need to merge into one `.Json` file:

The first file `start.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Start": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Start To Start",
        "body": [
    "MG_Start()"
        ],
        "description": "Start Cursor back to its start"
    }
}
```

The second file `end.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
        "body": [
    "MG_Move()"
        ],
        "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
    }
}
```

The Expected out I am aiming for is:

```
{
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Start": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Start To Start",
        "body": [
    "MG_Start()"
        ],
        "description": "Start Cursor back to its start"
    }
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
        "body": [
    "MG_Move()"
        ],
        "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
    }   
}
```

I have tried:

```
$Jstart = (Get-Content .\start.json -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
$JEnd = (Get-Content .\end.json -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

$Hash = [PSCustomObject]@{
    $Jstart = (Get-Content .\start.json -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
    $JEnd = (Get-Content .\end.json -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
}
```

but I get a undesired jumbled output:

```
{
  "@{MOUSE GESTURE L Start=}": {
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Start": {
      "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Start To Start",
      "body": "MG_Start()",
      "description": "Start Cursor back to its start"
    }
  },
  "@{MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end=}": {
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end": {
      "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
      "body": "MG_Move()",
      "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried variations but things just get worse.
Any ideas on how I can get this right? Thank you

---

EDIT:

@Santiago Squarzon

While solution works for the example I provided, I am getting problems trying to adapt it to my code.

The prblem I am having is, if one of the `.Json` files happens to have more than one object in it, like this:

```
{
    "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
        "body": [
    "MG_Move()"
        ],
        "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
    },

    "Another Snippet": {
        "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
        "body": [
    "MG_Move()"
        ],
        "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
    }
}
```

Then `$left.PSObject.Properties.Add($($right.PSObject.Properties))` failss, I get the error:

```
MethodException: 
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
```

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$JStart |Join $JEnd |ConvertTo-Json -Dept 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest to go about this would be to append one object to the other:

```bash
$left  = Get-Content .\start.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$right = Get-Content .\end.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($prop in $right.PSObject.Properties) {
    $left.PSObject.Properties.Add($prop)
}
$left | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

Resulting Json would look something like this:

```json
{
  "MOUSE GESTURE L Start": {
    "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Start To Start",
    "body": [
      "MG_Start()"
    ],
    "description": "Start Cursor back to its start"
  },
  "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end": {
    "prefix": "MOUSE GESTURE L Move To end",
    "body": [
      "MG_Move()"
    ],
    "description": "Move Cursor back to its end"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Santiago_Squarzon, Hey this works as intended for the example I provided, but I am getting an error when I use it with a json files that has a slight variation to it. I made an Edit to my Question with the error. Please take a look. Thanks allot for this.

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89 i see, try with the edit

Comment: Hey, I finally got around to testing it some more, your solution works now, Thanks!

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89 glad it does :) happy to help